# Node nested functions callback lost - Lex bot sessionAttributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, callback

I'm new to Node and asynchronous programming and I've tried everything I can find while studying to better understand callbacks.
This is for a Lex bot integration with Facebook, but I think I'm just lost in callback hell. My logs show that all the functions are working properly and the response is built and in time for Facebook not to time out, but it does timeout. So Facebook never receives the response and so I believe the callback never actually reaches the original function.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
...
        // get user info from Facebook
        var req = https.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+PSID+'?fields=first_name,last_name,gender&access_token='+pageAccessToken, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function (body) {
                console.log("BODY= "+body);

                body = JSON.parse(body);
                event.sessionAttributes['userInfo'] = {
                    "first_name": body['first_name'],
                    "last_name": body['last_name'],
                    "gender": body['gender'],
                    "id": body['id']
                };

                try {
                    intentProcessor (event, (response) => {
                        console.log("RESPONSE= "+ JSON.stringify(response));
                        callback(null, response);
                    });
                } catch (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
            });
        });
...
```

When `try` is placed outside of `res.on` the callback works and the response is sent, but it is sent before it gets the user data it needs.

When `try` is placed inside `res.on` (as shown in code above), the response logs perfectly with the user info. But it simply never makes it back to Facebook.

Can someone please explain how I am going wrong with handling the callback?

Comment: `data` is not the whole data passed but just a chunk. As its incomplete `JSON.parse` will fail. You might want to await the `end` event before parsing

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks, I'll be aware to change that if JSON.parse fails, but it does parse the info properly and doesn't error from what I can tell. Would that be silently failing and stopping the callback response?

Comment: No it would crash if it fails. However if this fails depends if the response is smaller than one chunk. So you should definetly fix this in the long term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long debugging, I found that the callbacks and nested functions were not the problem. The original callback was recognized at any level of the nested functions.

The real problem was that Amazon Lex bot does not accept nested Objects or Arrays inside of `sessionAttributes`.

This did not error in the Lambda function, so my logs appeared clean.
Removing `['userInfo']` and storing the sessionAttributes data as a single Object solved the problem.

```
event.sessionAttributes = {
    "first_name": body['first_name'],
    "last_name": body['last_name'],
    "gender": body['gender'],
    "id": body['id']
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below piece of code,

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/${PSID}fields=first_name,last_name,gender&access_token=${pageAccessToken}`;
  // get user info from Facebook
  var req = https.get(url, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  res.on('data', function (body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    event.sessionAttributes['userInfo'] = {
      "first_name": body['first_name'],
      "last_name": body['last_name'],
      "gender": body['gender'],
      "id": body['id']
    };
    intentProcessor(event, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      return callback(null, response);
    });
  });
});
```

}

Comment: @SurendaKumarB Thanks for attempting to answer, but returning the callback does not change the result. Still no response.

Comment: @jay but that `intentProcessor` has another callback signature ia definetly a thing...

Comment: Thanks I overlooked some edits in this answer. I've fully applied it now, improving the callback within `intentProcessor`. It looks like it works as much as what I had. And the response still does not make it all the way back to Facebook.

Comment: This answer was helpful in improving my callback code. Though callback ended up not being the problem. It was the formatting of nested objects inside of `sessionAttributes` that Lex does not accept.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the data from a response. You will need "promise". In ES7 async/await is a good way to deal with it. Use the library [request/request](https://github.com/request/request) or [request/promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) with the async/await of ES7 to make your code become work and cleaner. Please take a look at the code below.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let data = getFacebookData();
    //Do whatever you want to do using the data.
};
async function getFacebookData(){
    let dataFromFacebook=await request('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+PSID+'?fields=first_name,last_name,gender&access_token='+pageAccessToken);
    return JSON.parse(dataFromFacebook);
}
```

Comment: `data` is still a promise?